# conditional formatting on multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

i'm wanting to create conditional formatting for multiple criteria, i.e if cell meets all criteria, fill green, part criteria, fill amber and no criteria, fill red.

e.g if the control cell (A) is greater than all the figures below (

A   95.8%   90% 91% 91%

B   96.9%   95% 46% 46%
C   97.4%   95% 95% 95%
D   95.1%   92% 91% 92%
E   96.3%   93% 94% 93%

so the result will look like this
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scdw3.png)

Comment: `=A1>MAX(A2:A4)`

Comment: ok i'll try that, thanks

Comment: @RichardTompsett That was a great help, thank you completed formula
=AND(C5<MAX(C6:C9),C5>MIN(C6:C9)) (Amber)
=C5<MIN(C6:C9) (Red)
=C5>MAX(C6:C9) (Green)

Comment: I would if i new how, question was answered by @RichardTompsett and worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to return a boolean so something like `=A1>MAX(A2:A4)` will work

---

OP's final formula:

`=C5>MAX(C6:C9)` (Green)

`=AND(C5<MAX(C6:C9),C5>MIN(C6:C9))` (Amber)

`=C5<MIN(C6:C9)` (Red)